# How to call shutdown handler using batch file?

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a batch file that contains kill command to stop execution of my application but I just want my application to run the `ShutdownHandler` before stopping execution.

Same happens in my application when  use ctrl+c.

```
set /p evt=< bin/evtPid.txt
set /p jvt=< bin/jvtPid.txt
taskkill /pid %evt% 
taskkill /pid %jvt%
```

Comment: Your application such as what?

Comment: You can say it's a desktop application, that run's two consoles Simenteniously.

Comment: You can say anything you like, but until you provide some evidence it is meaningless. Specifically, show both the `ShutdownHandler` and how it is registered.

Comment: i just want to call shutdown hook using bat file

Comment: You haven't provided what you were asked for.

Comment: i'm looking for a perfect solution of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825995/how-to-do-graceful-shutdown-termination-of-java-processes]

Answer (score 0):

Normally Java does start the shutdown handler if you <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> it, but that’s not very clean or reliable. This should happen for taskkill, too as long as you do. ot use the /force option. (it might not work if there is no console windows, if sou have some service launcher).

So most Java servers implement some form of shutdown mechanism (for example tomcat has a dedicated shutdown socket and JBoss implements a shutdown command over its remoting socket.)